# Find and Highlight repeated words in Pages

Tags: pages

Is there a way, to find and then let those words or phrases remain highlighted in the document?

Comment: Have you considered doing a find/replace? replacing the target word with a shaded, colored or italic version for example

Comment: Check this link - https://support.apple.com/kb/PH23710?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US

Comment: Yeah. Find and replace will highlight that text for the particular moment. I wish, that text to stay highlighted in the normal document too.